# Utilizar resultado deSQL para inserir em uma outra tabela

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

O que estou querendo fazer é o seguinte:
Fazer uma busca em uma tabela, se achar o resultado. Com o resultado da busca, inserir o resultado em uma outra tabela.
Estou desenvolvendo em Nodejs, a princípio imagino que preciso ter uma variável que não seja local para poder armazenar o dado.
Faço a movimentação da variável local para a global, mas quando vou utilizar a variável ela está vazia.

Segue um trecho do meu código:

```
        qlq.query('SELECT idperfil FROM pefil WHERE nome= ? ', [NomepefilTratado], (err, rows) => {
          console.log('idperfil: ', rows)
          
          VarInserepefilproduto2         = rows
  
          console.log('VarInserepefilproduto2.idperfil: ',VarInserepefilproduto2)
  // no console está correto o valor

        })
        console.log('Antes de entrar no IF ',VarInserepefilproduto2)
  // no console VarInserepefilproduto2 está vazio
        if (VarInserepefilproduto2 != '') {
          console.log('Encontrei o pefil: VarInserepefilproduto: ',VarInserepefilproduto2)
              
          qlq.query(
  
            'INSERT INTO produto_pefil SET ?', VarInserepefilproduto2, (err, rows) => {
              console.log('VarInserepefilproduto2 produto_pefil: ',VarInserepefilproduto2)
            })
  
        } else {
          console.log('Menor que zero')
          
       //   var VarInsereA = {nome: NomepefilTratado}
       
          connection.finalizaconecao(qlq)       
          connection.conecaoteste()
          console.log('VarInsereA: ',NomepefilTratado)
          qlq.query(
  
            'INSERT INTO nome VALUES ?', NomepefilTratado, (err, rows) => {    })
```

Resumindo:
Quero utilizar o resultado da query para fazer um insert em uma outra tabela, faço a movimentação do campo.
Mas o resultado chega vazio.